# Using Geometry.fromJSON() gives unexpected results

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to use [Geometry.fromJSON()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Geometry.html#fromJSON) in the ArcGIS JSAPI 4.x to return a Point or an Extent geometry and I am getting some unexpected results.

Here is what I have tried.

```
const point = Geometry.fromJSON({x: 10, y: 10, spatialReference: {wkid: 4326}})
...and...
const point = Geometry.fromJSON({type: "point", x: 10, y: 10, spatialReference: {wkid: 4326}})
console.log(JSON.stringify(point.toJSON()))
```

Here is the result on the console.

```
{"spatialReference":{"wkid":4326}}
```

Should I be able to get a Point geometry with the JSON I am using with Geometry.fromJSON()?

My goal would be to do the following...

```
mapView.goTo(Geometry.fromJSON({....});
```

...using valid JSON for a Point or an Extent.

Comment: @user2856 based on your suggestion I tried `Geometry.fromJSON(JSON.stringify({x: 10, y: 10, spatialReference: {wkid: 4326}}))` and `Geometry.fromJSON({"x": 10, "y": 10, "spatialReference": {"wkid": 4326}})` and `Geometry.fromJSON('{"x": 10, "y": 10, "spatialReference": {"wkid": 4326}}')` but the results were the same.